# Solving a Nonlinear System Using Forward Euler

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the following nonlinear system of differential equations
$$\begin{align}
u_1'&=-3u_1u_2+u_3\\
u_2'&=-3u_1u_2+u_3\\
u_3'&=3u_1u_2-u_3.
\end{align}$$ I am trying to figure out how to go about approximating this system using forward Euler's method. I know I need to somehow linearize it, I'm just not sure of the best approach. One thought I had was to find the Jacobian
$$
J=\begin{bmatrix}-3u_2&-u_1&1\\-3u_2&-u_1&1\\3u_2&u_1&-1\end{bmatrix}.
$$ However, the farthest I went was finding the value of the time step for forward Euler that will ensure absolute stability. Still not really sure how to approximate the solution.

Comment: Why do you think you have to do anything to the equations to apply the Euler method? It is really as simple as it looks, you have just to replace the derivatives with the forward difference quotient.

Comment: @Moo: This is not necessarily wrong, it just implies that $u_2=u_1+c_1$ and $u_3=-u_1+c_2$, where the constants are determined by the initial conditions. This allows to reduce the system to one scalar equation $u_1'=-3u_1(u_1+c_1)-u_1+c_2$ that can be solved exactly via separation or as Bernoulli equation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann right, I see that now, thank you.